# Can "I are" be shortened to "I're"?

Tags: grammaticality, contractions

I just received a message containing "I're":

> Glad April and I're so different.

I've never seen this used before (I suppose as it's so unnecessary, saving just one character when writing) yet I can't find anything which claims that this *isn't* correct English.

Can "I are" be validly shortened to "I're"?

Comment: y' c'n short'n 'lmost anyth'n with 'postrophes when y'er quot'n someone's speech.

Comment: What month wrote this?

Comment: It depends on whether you're trying to reproduce colloquial speech or instead convey the meaning clearly.  Among other things, "I're" is apt to be read as "ire".

Comment: @JeffSahol One of the less-cruel ones, apparently.

Comment: If 're is pronounced as syllabic r, then "Alice and I're leaving" sounds okay in speech, but not if the r is non-syllabic.  (Compare "They're leaving" where the 're can be non-syllabic.)

Comment: This reminds me of Jeff Foxworthy's redneck words, like "mominem".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't use "I're." The usual term is I am, which shortens to "I'm."

But here, the context is "April and I" are...

The "are" doesn't refer to "I" but rather the whole phrase "April and I." That's why it can't be contracted.

Comment: I think this answer is more accurate than the more popular answer by Barrie England. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 11):

You won’t normally find it written, if that’s what you mean. However, you might hear something like it, particularly in rapid speech.

Comment: You **might** see it written where an author is attempting to represent the speaker accurately (rather like J K Rowling and *Harry Potter*).

Comment: Especially rapid speech from pirates.

Answer (score 2):

I have Googled for "he and you're", and I found very few examples (most examples have a clause ending with "he", followed by "and you're"). However, "he and you are" is quite common.

Furthermore, [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+and+you%27re%2Fhe+and+you+are%2Cyou%27re%2Fyou+are&year_start=1800&year_end=2009&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) considers "he and you're" so rare it doesn't plot it, while "you're" occurs at two-thirds the frequency of "you are". Similarly, neither "we and they're" nor "they and we're" are frequent enough to be plotted in Ngrams.

Based on these parallel constructions, I would say "you and I're" is very rare and ungrammatical. It appears that, at least in writing, you can't contract the verb when the subject is a compound joined by "and".

Personally, I wouldn't say "he and you're", "they and we're" or "we and they're", either, although I might pronounce "are" as /ər/ in any of these constructions. But notice that /wiər/ (*we er*) is pronounced differently than /wər/ (*we're*), at least in my dialect.

Answer (score -3):

No, you can't contract "I are" to "I're" because this does not represent a proper subject-verb agreement. The proper subject-verb agreement is "I am" and the contraction for this is "I'm". You can also contract "you are" to "you're".

Comment: In the example given, "I" is not the subject.

Comment: There's a bit of an answer hiding in here. For a contraction, you need a specific subject and matching verb, e.g. "you" and "are". You can't contract "he and you" and "are". While subject and verb match, the subject isn't one of the specific subjects for which a contraction exists. The question assumes that contraction works on an "adjacent word" basis, i.e. ungrammatically.

Answer (score -4):

Consider the word ire which defines anger. Contracting I and are to sound like another word could lead to some confusion in phonetics.

Comment: And apostrophe doesn’t ever mean “slang”.  And saying “I couldn’t’ve done it withoucha, so Mary and I’re planning to see ya at the awards ceremony to getcher fair share.”  That isn’t slang.

Comment: What do you consider that informal way of speech then if not as slang?

Comment: *Slang* is specialized vocabulary, words that mean something else than they normally mean or which are only known in that sense.